# Activity not reading intent from other class in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, android-intent

["Full" code](https://gist.github.com/Crowbrammer/a71137dbc1df2ec8ed29fd1c2dafb378).

I believe that **the DisplayMessageActivity class should read the EXTRA_MESSAGE string (constant), via the intent from the MainActivity class.**

But it's not doing that, despite [copy-and-pasting the code from Google/Android's own tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Android SDK says it cannot resolve the symbols: 'EXTRA_MESSAGE' and 'textView'. Ideas on how to resolve this--as well as ***how to think about this in the future***?

Here is a ["video screenshot" of the SDK](https://youtu.be/-k64jAlG0d0), too.

Comment: Will people start giving *reasons* for downvoting, so that I may know how to better write my questions? I can't do anything to help unless you tell me what's wrong...

Comment: You tried good to explain things with code etc though next time add complete error details , or a snapshot in these cases (along with code as well here) though you are learning (like we are as well) so sometime member can have different views so best is focus on learning by embracing it,use google ,avoid criticism and yeah sometime you tends to see downvotes without any comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define that constant in `MainActivity` as

```
 public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extra_message";
```

so that in `DisplayMessageActivity` you can access that `static` constant as

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extra_message";
    // static : accessed by class name
    // final : value cannot be changed  

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

**DisplayMessageActivity**

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //..code    
        String message = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        //..code    
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I wiped out my constant definition with an Alt + Enter function. Thanks for pointing this out. Now I need to figure out what's up with the textView symbol...

Comment: @AaronBell i am glad that could help , apologies for replying late , caught up by some work, about textview , just make sure you have right `id` and layout  and a successful build is done , letme know is still there's an issue

Answer (score 1):

You can define a global variable

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Message";
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,value);
```

and can get it on other activity by-

```
String getMessage= intent.getStringExtra(YourActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Thats it.